# Python equivalent of the ! operator

Tags: python, operators

For the following construct what can the more pythonic way?

If it were C I could just use `!` but what is it equivalent in Python?

```
file_path = # something 
if os.path.exists(file_path):
     pass
else:
  file_path = # make new path
```

Comment: with python syntax, it quite often works to try plain english!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file_path = # something 
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
     file_path = #make new path
```

[Python Docs - Expressions - 5.1 Boolean Expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: Silly me ! forgot completely about 'not' construct. thanks @cularis

Answer (score 1):

The `not` keyword.

```
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    file_path ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
file_path = # something 
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    file_path = # make new path
```

Operator `not` is also in C++, btw, as a synonym for `!`.